# ¿Cómo configurar correctamente Drupal 8 para que este detrás de un proxy?

Tags: apache2, proxy, drupal8

Estoy levantando un proyecto de Drupal 8 con https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal, funciona correctamente, puedo acceder al proyecto sin problemas, hacer login, adjuntar archivos, etc...

Pero cuando pongo un proxy por delante, en este caso un proxy montado con Apache no me deja hacer login, como si no reconociera el dominio como válido o no me reconociera las cookies como buena., pero puedo navegar por la web como usuario anónimo sin problema.

Este es el virtual host que monta el proxy de apache:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName labo.local

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ProxyPass "/" "http://labo.docker.localhost:8000/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://labo.docker.localhost:8000/"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/labo.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/labo.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Y esta es la configuración que tengo para proxies en el archivo settings.php

```
$settings['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$settings['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$settings['reverse_proxy_trusted_headers'] =  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR | 
  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO | 
  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT; 

$settings['trusted_host_patters'] = [
  '^labo\.local$', 
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`trusted_host_patters` debería ser `trusted_host_patterns`.

`'^labo\.local$'` no corresponde con `http://labo.docker.localhost`, o cuál sería la uri desde la que haces el proxy?